# How do you use find and xargs to move files from a folder within a folder to another folder?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, xargs

I am trying to move files within the filecontainer folder into the example1 folder.

The directory structure is:

```
/example1

/example2/filecontainer
```

example1 has nothing in it.

example2 has a folder named filecontainer and three files in it called example1.sh, example2.sh and example3.sh

I tried the command below but none of the files were moved.

```
find ./ -name "example*.sh" | xargs -I% mv % example1
```

Essentially I want to move files within a subfolder to another folder. I am able to move files from a folder to another but when it the folder is a subfolder, it does not work.

I have to use the find and xargs since I will later on filter files from today up to a year and only move those files from a sub folder to a folder.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need `find` or `xargs` at all? Your shell will happily do things for you:

`mv -t /example1 /example2/filecontainer/example.*`

if you indeed got a more complicated scheme where you actually *need* find, you can do a number of things; among these

- Use `find`'s `-exec` option
- use `find [location] [-options, such as -name] -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t {target directory}`. Note that `-print0` makes find separate the file names with a zero byte, which is great, because other delimiters like spaces or newlines are absolutely legal to have in file names; `-0` makes xargs look for zero bytes instead of linebreaks

The problem with your code, by the way, is that you're using very strange quotation marks: your `“` isn't `"`, and it makes a difference for your computer.

Comment: The problem for me seems to be that when there is a folder within a folder, I am unable to move the files from the folder within a folder to another folder. When I simple have two separate folders and one has three files, I could move it using xargs...